# What does the sun product of price times quantity divided by average price

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, price-index

I have a very simple question, what is the meaning, if any, of this?

I.e. Economically what does the following calculation mean?

$$
\left(\frac{(Q1\cdot P1)+(Q2\cdot P2)+(Q3\cdot P3)}{Q1 + Q2 + Q3}\right)
$$

Consider the values being in a table like the one shown below:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{Factory A Generation of good x} & \text{Factory B Generation of good x} & \text{Market price for good x} \\
\hline
1 & Q1 & Q1 & P1 \\
2 & Q2 & Q2 & P2 \\
3 & Q3 & Q3 & P3 
\end{array}
$$

Thank you!

Comment: The previous answer is correct. You can also say that this is the average cost per item produced as Q *P = Cost of production. Where as costs= revenue , theoretically speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Q_i P_i$ is the total revenue from good $i$. So dividing total revenue from all goods by the amount produced of all of them should give us something like "average revenue per item produced"?